# Module not found: Can't resolve 'pg-hstore' sequelize and nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sequelize.js, next.js13

I'm using Nextjs 13 to create a full-stack app and use Sequelize to handle the `MySQL` database.
I have `api` folder to handle my admin form.
in `src/pages/api/test.js`

when I call my model It works correctly and without error and all of my table has been created:

`src/pages/api/test.js` code:

```
import { Contact } from "../../../models/models";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const contact = await Contact.findByPk(1);
  return res.status(200).json({ message: "Hello World!", contact });
}
```

but when I use my contact model in my `src/app/(admin)/admin/contact/page.js` I got an error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'pg-hstore'`

error screen shot:

[image]

`src/app/(admin)/admin/contact/page.js` code:

```
import { AdminCard } from "../../../../../components/admin/UI/admin-components";
import AdminContactForm from "../../../../../components/admin/pages/contact-form";

import { Contact } from "../../../../../models/models";

async function AdminContact(props) {
  // const data = await Contact.findByPk(1);

  return (
    <AdminCard title="Contact">
      {/* <AdminContactForm data={data} /> */}
    </AdminCard>
  );
}

export default AdminContact;
```

model `contact.js` code:

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "./database";

const Contact = sequelize.define("contact", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  address: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  instagram: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  facebook: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  linkedin: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  whatsapp: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
});

sequelize
  .sync()
  .then((result) => {
    // console.log("result1 => ", result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {});

export default Contact;
```

I'm using Mysql, not Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved by running `npm install pg-hstore`.

Comment: why does it need pg-hstore, if `mysql` db is used?

Comment: Adding an unnecessary dependency does not "solve" this issue.